# Why is Array.from's callback much slower than the map function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, map-function

When doing some performance tests today I found that [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)'s callback work pretty slower than running the [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function independently.

Tests were done on 32000000 items long array in the following manner.

```js
let t1;
const arr = Array.from(new Array(32000000), (v,i) => {
    if (i === 0) t1 = performance.now();
    return i;
});
let t2 = performance.now();

t2 - t1; // ~4500ms


let arr2 = Array.from(new Array(32000000));
arr2 = arr2.map((v,i) => {
    if (i === 0) t1 = performance.now();
    return i;
});
t2 = performance.now();

t2 - t1; // ~500ms
```

I always thought the `Array.from` just runs the `map` function on itself when the array gets created. The polyfills' code looks alike too. Any idea why is there such a difference in performance?

Tested in Google Chrome 74.0.3729.157, macOS

Comment: A piece of advice: In performance measurement use cases, always try to run your tests in different orders, as things outside of your control (e.g., current state of the cache) may impact the result. In your example - try to run the second block of code before the first block of code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Of course I did that, just forget to mention it. There's no difference in the results.

Comment: I don't see why you'd alter your tests including an unecessary `if`. You can safely set the timer before running the test. Also, your question has to do with the javascript engine of your browser. You have to run it across multiple browsers (and versions, where available), and across multiple platforms. In current form, your question is poorly tagged and unanswerable.

Comment: you might try adding a third formal param to your from() callback. i know map() was optimized for a long time to run fastest only when variadic args matched formal params. maybe they haven't /can't optimize from() in the same manner that the eventually tweaked [].map().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the mapping function that is slow, **it is the `Array.from` call itself**.

If we remove all the unnecessary variables and conditional statements we get the following simplified benchmark, which returns:

Chrome 74:

```
Array.from with map: 4735.970ms
Array.map: 166.405ms
Array.map with from: 5101.585ms
Array.from: 4999.910ms
```

Firefox 67:

```
Array.from with map: 729.000ms
Array.map: 41.000ms
Array.map with from: 1150.000ms
Array.from: 619.000ms
```

So we can see that the mapping actually takes almost no time, all that is taking the bulk time is the `Array.from` call.

I assume `Array.from` is a lot slower to allocate memory for and create the new Array than the one returned by `Array.map` just because it is a lot more generic and complex than the map function. Just compare their specs: [Array.prototype.map](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19) vs [Array.from](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.from), `Array.from` seems a lot harder to optimize the compiler for.

```js
const arr = new Array(32000000);

console.time('Array.from with map');
const arr1 = Array.from(arr, (v,i) => {
    return i;
});
console.timeEnd('Array.from with map');


console.time('Array.map');
const arr2 = arr.map((v,i) => {
    return i;
});
console.timeEnd('Array.map');



console.time('Array.map with from');
const arr3 = Array.from(arr).map((v,i) => {
    return i;
});
console.timeEnd('Array.map with from');

console.time('Array.from');
const arr4 = Array.from(arr);
console.timeEnd('Array.from');
```

Comment: `Array.from` calls the mapping function while creating each item whereas the map function iterates each item after the array is created. So, there's no difference in callbacks at all, the only thing is that Array.from calls it while it's creating the array (which takes some time) and map just iterates the already existing one.